# Codeigniter when calling library method I get HTTP 500 error

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to create a library (in application/libraries) but I'm having problems when I call it from the controller.

Below is the code in the controller

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Client extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('security');
        }

        function index() {
            try {
                $activation_code = 'aa';
                $this->security->Check_User_By_ValidationCode($activation_code);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                log('error', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And this is what I have in the library

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Security {

        var $CI;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
        }

        public function Check_User_By_ValidationCode($activation_code) {
            return $activation_code ;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

But I'm getting a "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request." in Chrome.
I'm not able to get anything from logs so I can't tell what I'm doing wrong here.
Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the class `security` because that class is defined by CodeIgniter. Just change the name to something else, like "Auth" or something more descriptive.

See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/security.html